# How to chain a function to this one after it completes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

For some reason the bootstrap timepicker seems to reset my form elements on its hide event. So I'd like to make a temp workaround, but I'd like to be able to have another function be called immediately after this one

```
$('#EventTimeEdit').timepicker()
                   .on('hide.timepicker', function (e) {
                   }
 );
```

Say I want to call foo after the above finishes

```
function foo(){


};
```

For some reason it doesn't behave how I want if I call foo from within the above method, so I'm wondering if I can call it after it executes (every time .timepicker...on executes)

Comment: Please make sure to tag questions appropriately. Also, make sure to *explain* what "isn't working": does the event not fire? Does the event fire, but still trigger the "reset"? Is there a TypeError raised somewhere? Etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#EventTimeEdit').timepicker().on('hide.timepicker', function (e) {
    // Do optional stuff
    anotherFunction();
});
```

Where `anotherFunction();` is your not yet created function to execute after the timepicker hides

Comment: @seavaor yeah I tried that before, but I'd like anotherFunction() to happen strictly and always after the .on finished entirely..